# How to write the table width in the log file?

Tags: tables

How do I write the table width in the log file? Say, for instance, that I have 2 tables -- when I compile the tex file, I want to write the width/breadth in the log file. Is that possible through a macro or definition, because I need to use this in my own template, rather than in a file

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline
Case & Method
\#1 & Method
\#2 & Method
\#3\\
\hline
1 & 50 & Sample Piece & 970\\
2 & 47 & Sample Piece & 230\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline
Case & Method
\#1 & Method
\#2 & Method
\#3\\
\hline
1 & 50 & Sample Piecedgjgh aweg & 970\\
2 & 47 & Sample Piece & 230\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to save the dimensions of the `tabular` environments or those of the `table` environments?

Comment: @Mico Actually i need to get the tabular environment

Answer (score 6):

This cannot measure the caption width...only the `tabular` width.  It works by placing the `tabular` in a temporary box, and using `\typeout` to print the width into the log file.

EDITED to place this in its own environment, `mtabular` (measure tabular).  Additionally, `mtabular` now has an optional argument, to use as the ID, if the default use of `\thetable` is not appropriate (depending on usage).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe,environ}
\newenvironment{mtabular}[2][\thetable]{%
  \gdef\savemtabopt{#1}%
  \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\begin{tabular}{#2}}{\end{tabular}\egroup\copy0
  \typeout{Table \savemtabopt. width is \the\wd0.}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results}
\begin{mtabular}{c c c c}
\hline
Case & Method
\#1 & Method
\#2 & Method
\#3\\
\hline
1 & 50 & Sample Piece & 970\\
2 & 47 & Sample Piece & 230\\
\hline
\end{mtabular}%
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results}
\begin{mtabular}{c c c c}
\hline
Case & Method
\#1 & Method
\#2 & Method
\#3\\
\hline
1 & 50 & Sample Piecedgjgh aweg & 970\\
2 & 47 & Sample Piece & 230\\
\hline
\end{mtabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is that possible through a macro or definition, because i need to use this in my own Teamplate, rather than file

Comment: @user52124 Please see my revised answer, introducing the `mtabular` environment.